# When a treasure is recovered do you remove those treasure cards from the deck?

Tags: forbidden-island

When using your four cards to get a treasure item do the treasure cards (and any extras that may be drawn or in another's possession) get removed from the game? This seems to drastically increase the number of times Waters Rise is drawn since the deck gets thinner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

> When you capture a treasure, discard cards to the Treasure discard pile and move the
>   figurine in front of you.

This is also where encountered *Waters Rise!* cards are placed.

> Discard the Waters Rise! card to the Treasure discard pile.

Comment: The treasure cards are effectively useless once you use them to get the corresponding treasures, but they do remain in the deck.  If they did come out, it would both make it far too easy to get the remaining treasures, and with less padding on the Waters Rise cards, cause the island to accelerate its sinking to a really absurd degree.